# How to get Point values from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have a small problem that I hope is easy to solve. In the code below on the second row I have `path1.moveTo...` but instead of using the `touchDownX1` and `touchDownY1` coordinates, I thought it would be better to use the first values of `X` and `Y` from the `touchPoints[0]`, but I don't know how?

```
// Path 1
path1.moveTo(touchDownX1, touchDownY1);
for(Point point: touchPoints[0]) {
path1.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
canvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to draw points for all the points in the arrayList ? Or just for the first point in the array ?

Comment: I guess I must use path1.moveTo.... to start the line and then draw the rest of the line?? Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see the interest of making a loop to draw just the first point.

Comment: @ZouZou In the loop I draw the rest of the path while the finger is moving on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `touchPoints.get(0)` because the `[index]` notation only works for arrays, not ArrayLists.

**Edit:**
The rest of the code should work. The way you access x and y is perfectly fine, assuming that the first element touchPoints is a *list of points*. If the *first element* of touchPoints is a *single point,* do not use a loop, just do `touchPoints.get(0).x` and the same for y.

**Edit:**
The `moveTo` method should only be called for the beginning of a contour/shape to set its starting point. There is no reason to call it more than that for a single contour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, but I guess I must also write: touchPoints.get(0).x ??

Comment: You should only write `touchPoints.get(0).x` if you are not using the for loop to go through the points in the first element of touchPoints.

Comment: OK, but I guess I must start the drawing of the path like I do?